# StringIndexOutOfBoundException when clicking on item from a list view

Tags: java, android, eclipse

i have a list view withe data retrieved from database which suppose to navigate to another activity if i clicked on an item..

however im getting this error when i click on an item

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
ComponentInfo{com.example.anistat/com.example.anistat.MemberExercise}:
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=9
```

and this is the list onItemClick function

```
    private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager 
          = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
}
Boolean net;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_member_exercise);
    setTitle("AniStat");
    net=isNetworkAvailable();

    if(net){

    Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.membernextex);

    btnDownloadPDF = (Button) findViewById(R.id.memberexsavepdf);
    btnDownloadPDF.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    // getting data
    Intent i = getIntent();
    eid = i.getStringExtra("ID");
    cha = i.getStringExtra("chapter");
    lev = i.getStringExtra("level");
    user = i.getStringExtra("user");
    id = i.getStringExtra("eid");// 1 2 3
    id = id.substring(9);

    if (!id.equals("")){

    if (id.equals("1")) {
        nextid = "2";
    }
    if (id.equals("2")) {
        nextid = "3";

    }
    if (id.equals("3")) {
        next.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    }}
```

what is the problem ?

Comment: Error is into oncreate() of MemberExercise, not into the given code above. Add that code here.

Comment: How did you define that problem is in this part? Please, post your full code or this part which shows log. In this part no problem.

Comment: @Daryn because when i clivk on an item i got the error so i thought its in this part

Comment: @PankajKumar MemberExercise works fine if i open it from home

Comment: Problem is at `id = id.substring(9);`. Add null and size check here for id. I think either you are not sending id from list-onclick.

Comment: @PankajKumar oh right !!!! SOLVED ! THANK YOU SO MUCH !!!